# Conditional reverse name in Django template URL tag

Tags: django, django-templates, url-pattern

Is it possible to pass an argument contains reverse name to the Django template URL tag

For example:

`note: In this example`**conditional_URL**`is not a reverse name.`

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('views',
    url(r'^iframeViewURL/$', 'iframeView', name='iframeView'),
    url(r'^url_a/', 'view_a', name='view_a'),
    url(r'^url_b/', 'view_b', name='view_b'),
)
```

view.py:

```
def iframeView(**kwargs):
    kw = kwargs
    if kw['condition']:
        conditional_url = 'view_a'  # name of the URL pattern
    else:
        conditional_url = 'view_b'  # name of the URL pattern
    return render_to_response('iframe.html', {'conditional_URL': conditional_url},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request, {}))

def view_a(*args):
    pass

def view_b(*args):
    pass
```

iframe.html:

```
<iframe src="{% url conditional_URL *args %}">
</iframe>
```

I try this but it's not working because of the conditional_URL is not a name of any url pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible since Django 1.3 if you add `{% load url from future %}` to your templatetag:

```
{% load url from future %}
<iframe src="{% url conditional_URL arg1 arg2 %}">
</iframe>
```

In Django 1.5 it is no longer necessary to add `{% load url from future %}`.

See the "Forwards compatibility" in the [Django Documentation for the `url` templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#url) for more information

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the name of url pattern to template, it will be easier to resolve and pass actual url to template.

Something like:

```
def iframeView(**kwargs):
    kw = kwargs
    if kw['condition']:
        conditional_url = 'name_a'  # name of the URL pattern
    else:
        conditional_url = 'name_b'  # name of the URL pattern

    return render_to_response('iframe.html', 
                          {'conditional_URL': reverse(conditional_url)},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request, {}))
```

Then in template

```
<iframe src="{{conditional_URL}}"> </iframe>
```

Comment: Ok it looks like quite simple, but how about *args in {% url %} above example?

Comment: One too many `)` in the return statement, and this `conditional_url_actual = ` is a syntax error.